# Open a query based on the dates selected on the report

Tags: date, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a database which shows all the patients we have and when they had a vaccination with our organization.

I have created a query (called `Patient_Diagnosis`) which shows what vaccination and the date of that vaccination a patient has had.

A form (called `Report Menu`) has also been created. The form will allow the user to select a `Start Date` and an `End Date` and then click a button which opens the query. But the query should be filtered by the date selected.

I have been able to filter the dates in the `Patient_Diagnosis` Query on the Criteria row in design view by entering

```
>=CDate([Forms]![frmReport Menu]![StartDate]) And <=CDate([Forms]![frmReport Menu]![EndDate])
```

However, once I open the query, it requests me to manually enter the dates.

What I want it to do is correspond with the `Report Menu`.

1. The user should open the `Report Menu`
2. Then select the dates (through a calendar style option)
3. Click the 'Run' button which opens the `Patient_Diagnosis` Query
4. The Query should be filtered by the dates selected.

Any ideas?

Comment: I do it for you, Now please remove comments ;).

Comment: Check your spelling. For instance, is it [Report Menu] or [frmReport Menu]?